# flask error sending POST and GET to same function,

Tags: python, post, flask, jinja2, werkzeug

This is a function which (in a GET request) receives a case_url and case_key and serves the corresponding case (using mongoDB) to a html template called detail_case. 
Im trying to add a feature where when a form is filled(on this same page detail_case) and it is submitted, it should submit a POST request to the same function and the code under 'if request.method=="POST"' should get executed.

```
@app.route('/case/<case_url>/<case_key>', methods=["GET","POST"])
def serve_case(case_url,case_key):
"""for saving a comment in db.comments"""
if request.method == "POST":    

    text=request.form['comment_text']
    #code which inserts it in the database

    return redirect(url_for('serve_case', \
    case_url=case_url,\
    case_key="Highlights"))

"""
Function serves the case as per the key indicated in the URL
"""

#corresponding code here which fills values of variables and sends it to another page

return render_template('detail_case.html')
```

The problem is that I don't think the POST request is ever executed. This is the html code on the template page detail_case-

```
<textarea placeholder="Please enter your comments here" action="{{ url_for('serve_case',case_url=case_url,case_key=case_key)}}" method="POST" name="comment_text" rows="6"></textarea><br />
```

The problem i think is the action field. I don't know how should I send the variable comment_text to my function. Infact, the code under POST does not get executed when I submit. 
Basically the issue is that during a GET request, it sends 2 variables which are needed in the parameters of the function serve_case. During my POST request, well, I don't know how to exactly frame the action field. If I send no parameters, its an error. If I don't send it to the same function, then how will it execute the POST code? Could someone please suggest sumthing?
**i'm pretty new to flask, i'm editing someone else's code**

Comment: Use something like Firebug or Chrome Dev tools to see what is the url that you are hitting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to submit the POST request (for example through form) like below:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('serve_case',case_url=case_url,case_key=case_key)}}" method="POST">
 <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter your comments here">
 <input type="submit"   name="comment_text" rows="6"><br />
</form>
```

Comment: Oh yes, of course, i wasn't submitting it at all. Silly me. Thank you very much.